# $f(n) = \sum_{i=n + 1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$ is $O(n^{-1})?$

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

If $f(n)$ is the sequence defined above, is it $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

I am not sure if this is true, but I feel like it might be and would help me prove something else, if true.

I don't have much of an idea how to start - of course, if I just wanted
$$ \sum_{i = n+1} \frac{1}{i^2} \leq \frac{C_n}{n} $$
for some $C_n$ depending on $n$, then this is clearly true, but I want a constant independent of $n$ there.

Comment: You can [compare to the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) of $1/t^2$ from $n+1$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the bound (look at the curve and the staircase representing the sum):

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i \ge n + 1} \frac{1}{i^2}
    &\le \int_n^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{u^2} \\
    &= \frac{1}{n} 
\end{align*}$

Comment: I like this - it is generalizable to $f(n) = \sum_{i = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{1+\delta}}$ for any $\delta > 0$.

Comment: @Anu, the beauty is that it extends to *any* convergent $\sum_{i \ge n} g(i)$ if $g(i) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is true. Note that $$f(n) = \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2} \le \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i(i-1)} = \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{i-1}-\dfrac{1}{i}\right) = \dfrac{1}{n},$$ where we have used the fact that the last sum telescopes.

In case you are curious, you can also get a lower bound in a similar manner as follows: $$f(n) = \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2} \ge \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i = n+1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{i}-\dfrac{1}{i+1}\right) = \dfrac{1}{n+1}.$$